# Find Last row in column VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code

```
Range("C31").Select

Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
```

Working fine if 2 or more lines pasted in C31. But It has error if C31 has only 1 line item as xlDown will go to the bottom of the file and Offset 1,0 will totally not work.

Is there a better code for "Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select"?

if found 1 line in C31 to use code is:
Range("C31").Offset(1, 0).Select.. and vice versa..

Cant seem to find simple code, for simple IF code

Comment: ... and to improve your code, study [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but this would work:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("C31").Select
If Selection.Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
End If
```

Try this variation:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Select
If Selection.Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
End If
If Selection.Row <> 1048576 Then
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
```

Comment: Thank you! But still in C31, i expect to move 1 down in C32.

Comment: Would this work: just check that you are not on the last row and move down one row.